# Yii2 ActiveForm Stripe token

Tags: yii2, xmlhttprequest

In Yii2, we are using \Stripe\Charge::create following the site's documentation example:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges

Everything works great as long we use straight HTML in the views, but when we embed the card-element  in an ActiveForm, the stripe.js returns:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens due to
>   access control checks.

We would like to use ActiveForm to simplify the validation and handling of other fields on the form.  Any help?

Best,
Joe

Comment: The error is CORS related. See [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone landing here, the only way I can get this to work is to remove the ActiveForm scaffolding.  Real bummer because I've had to validate the non-Stripe input fields with Javascript, which is lot more work.

I do challenge anyone to post working code in Yii using ActiveForm that will return a token.  I don't think it can be done...but I would love to be wrong.

Best,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

The error is CORS related, see [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Use the appropriate `Access-Control` as described there.

You can use Yii's build in behavior [yii\filters\Cors](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-cors) in your controller.

Try first without any restriction:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        ],
    ];
}
```

If it works, than you can restrict the access by parametrising the behavior, something like that:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => [https://api.stripe.com'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST', 'PUT'],
            ],

        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But no joy.  I tried the first "without any restriction" example you posted and get the same result.

Comment: You should see in response header: `access-control-allow-origin: *`

Comment: Yes, access-control-allow-origin: * does appear in the header.

Comment: I can not analyze further the problem without code. What does it mean `stripe.js returns...` exactly? Which function call generates the error? Such error comes basically from your browser.

Comment: My code was lifted from the Stripe site.  It basically requests a token and then attaches it to a hidden field on the form: <code>    
stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                ...
            } else {
                // Send the token to your server.
                stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
        }); </code> I believe it is when accessing the result.token that I get the message.  This does NOT happen when I remove the ActiveForm scaffolding.

Comment: Do you  see any message in the browser's console?

Comment: Just the one I mention in the beginning: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens due to access control checks.